Prove that the Halting problem is undecidable by reducing the Accept problem to the Halting problem
I was very confusing on reducing the Accept problem to Halting problem.
The accept problem: decide whether a given Turing machine M accepts a given input w.
The halting problem: decide whether a Turing machine H which takes as input any Turing machine M and any input w to M such that

H always terminates
H accepts If M halts on w
H rejects If M does not halt on w

I'm not particularly sure on how to use contradiction for this...
Could anyone help me out

Perhaps you could add more information about what you've considered so far, or what specificaly confuses you. I don't think you are expected to do any tricks in the logical part. The halting problem is presumed to be undecidable. So, your job is only to show how to solve the accept problem given a solution to the halting problem.
